# when condition to evaluate list of values inside with_items

Tags: ansible

My intention with below playbook is to run a shell command only when it finds any of the value from disk_list. I need help to frame out when condition as told above.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
     disk_list:
      - sda
      - sdb
      - sdc

  - name: Get df -hT output to know XFS file system
    shell: df -hT |grep xfs|awk '{print $1}'
    register: df_result

  - name: Run shell command on each XFS file system
    shell: ls -l {{ item }} | awk '{print $1}'
    with_items: "{{ df_result.stdout_lines }}"
    when: "{{ disk_list.[] }} in {{ item }}"
```

BTW, in my system, "df_result" variable looks as below:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "df_result": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "df -hT |grep xfs|awk '{print $1}'", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.017588", 
        "end": "2019-03-01 23:55:21.318871", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2019-03-01 23:55:21.301283", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "/dev/sda3\n/dev/sda1", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "/dev/sda3", 
            "/dev/sda1"
        ]
    }
}
```

Please help !

Comment: It's not clear what is disk_list variable. And what error message you receive?

Comment: - set_fact:
     disk_list:
      - sda
      - sdb
      - sdc

this is just a variable defined as fact to have a match in when condition. Expectation is to run the shell commands only when item matches any value in disk_list.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes on the playbook.

1. For localhost, connection: local is implicit. So there is no technical need to specify this.
2. set_fact is correct, but in this case I believe is more appropiate to use "vars" at a play level instead of the set_fact module in a task. This also allows you to use "vars_files" for easier use of disk device lists.
3. I would reccomend to try to keep your task names "easy", as you may want to use the --start-at-task option at some point.
4. with_items is depricated in favor of "loop".
5. The conditional "when" works at a task level. So it will execute the task (for all its items) if the condition is met.

Here is a working version of what you need which also reflects the (5) recommendations made:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    disk_list:
      - sda
      - sdb
      - sdc

   tasks:

    - name: cleans previous runs
      shell: cat /dev/null > /tmp/df_result

    - name: creates temporary file
      shell: df -hT | grep ext4 | grep -i {{ item }} | awk '{print $1}' >> /tmp/df_result
      loop: "{{ disk_list }}"

    - name: creates variable
      shell: cat /tmp/df_result
      register: df_result

    - name: shows info
      shell: ls -l {{ item }} | awk '{print $1}'
      loop: "{{ df_result.stdout_lines }}"
```

I basically just use a temporary file (/tmp/df_result) with the results you need already filtered by the "grep -i {{ item }}" used in the loop on task "creates temporary file". Then, the loop in "shows info" just iterates over an already clean list of items.

To see the result on screen, you could use "-v" option when running the playbook or if you want to save the result in a file, you could add " >> /tmp/df_final" at the end of the shell line in "shows info" task.

I accidently step on this post, which is kind of old. I'm sure you already fixed this in your environment, maybe you find a better way to do it, hopefully you did.

Regards,